# ODBC connection to Microsoft SQL Server native DB from C# .NET console application code

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure, odbc

I have been struggling with a connection problem to a Database Server which I can perfectly access via the Web Browser (the DBMS is of Microsoft SQL Server type, allocated in an Azure server at: https://dr1ildtnid.database.windows.net/).

However, besides having tried with lots of configurations of the connection string parameters, I keep having always the same exception when executing:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]
>   Data source name not found and no default driver specified

This is a sample of my code:

```
string MyConString = "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=dr1ildtnid.database.windows.net,1433;Database=imev_afternoon_2;User=<MYUSERNAME>@dr1ildtnid;Password=<MYPASSWORD>;Encrypt=yes;Connection Timeout=30";

System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection MyConnection = new OdbcConnection(MyConString);
MyConnection.Open();
```

Also, in the User parameters I also tried my username without the "@...." suffix. please any help with this issue I need solved urgentyl would be greatly appreciated.
thanks!

Comment: ODBC data sources are kept separated for 32bit and 64bit apps What is you TargetCPU ? Did you use the corresponding ODBC Administrator to define the DataSource?

Comment: Why do you use ODBC? Seems legacy, old, not very well supported - I'd much rather use the **native** .NET SQL client - much easier to work with!

Comment: Indeed if you are using ODBC for accessing any of the database with native .Net provider, the its not a good option, especially because ODBC is a generic provider meant to connect to all kinds of database using COM based ODBC layer

Comment: Are you sure you have the SQL Server 2008 native client installed on the machine?  The last native client ODBC driver is "SQL Server Native Client 11.0".  The latest Microsoft SQL Server ODBC driver is "ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server".    I agree with the other comments that SqlClient is always the best option to access SQL Server from .NET code.

Comment: thank you everybody. I have 64 bit machine. based on the comments, it seems a good idea to use SqlClient instead of ODBC to connect to the DB. Can you please draft me an example on how would the use of SqlClient affect the connection string I should use?

Comment: Ok based on this example at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C and deleting the "TrustedConnection=yes" parameter from the connection String, I got it working :-) Thanks

Comment: According to the provided link, ODBC is faster than native! http://www.harveysoft.com/cps_pgs/datadirect/faster-than-native-final.pdf and http://www.vmsodbc.com/products/data_access/odbc-sql-azure-driver/index.html#section=tab-1